# Check through the use of a list if a term exist

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df  <-data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), stock_1 = c("Google","Microsoft","Yahoo"), stock_2 = c("Yahoo","Gg","NA"))
```

with this I know the following are in the same group:

```
mylist <- c("Google", "Gg")
```

Having the previous list how is it possible to run the mylist through all rows and check if exist or not using 1 or 0 respectively. If the value more than one times in the same row it takes again the 1.

Example of output

```
df  <-data.frame(id = c(1,2,3), stock_1 = c("Google","Microsoft","Yahoo"), stock_2 = c("Yahoo","Gg","NA"), mylist = c(1,1,0))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use the `apply` function to iterate over the rows of `df`:

```
apply(df, 1, function(x) max(x %in% mylist))
# 1 1 0
```

We can store the result of this function in a new column:

```
df$mylist <- apply(df, 1, function(x) max(x %in% mylist))

#   id   stock_1 stock_2 mylist
# 1  1    Google   Yahoo      1
# 2  2 Microsoft      Gg      1
# 3  3     Yahoo      NA      0
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Vectorized way using `do.call` to paste the columns and then using `grepl` to detect the words in your `mylist`, i.e.

```
as.integer(grepl(paste(mylist, collapse = '|'), do.call(paste, df[-1])))
#[1] 1 1 0
```